# Detect a straight automatically in Texas Hold em Poker

Tags: javascript

I made a Poker-Hands tracker. The 52 cards of the game are in this program represented by their value and their type.

For example Ace-heart is stored as "Ah" and 7-spades as "7h".

In order to check for a simple Straight I have generated this code, where the array cards is a sorted array with the cards on the table and the cards the player has:

```
 for (let i = 0; i <= 5; i++) {
        if (cards[i + 1] - 1 == cards[i]) {
          x = x + 1;
        }
    
        if (x == 4) {
          console.log("straight");
        }
      }
```

The code works fine for simple Straights like 2,3,4,5,6 . But I wanted to check for Straights including J's,Q's,K's and A's.

Therefore I have generated this code:

```
  function check(A, B) {

    A.sort(function (a, b) {
      return a.itemCommodity > b.itemCommodity;
    })
    B.sort(function (a, b) {
      return a.itemCommodity > b.itemCommodity;
    })

    let y = 0;
    for (let i = 0; i < A.length; i++) {
      if (A[i] == B[i])
        y++;
    }
    if (y == 5) {
      console.log("Straight");
      return true;
    }

  }



if (check(cards,["A", "2", "3", "4", "5"])) {
   console.log("Straight");
  }

  if (check(cards,["A", "K", "Q", "J", "10"])) {
    console.log("Royal Straight");
  }

  if (check(cards,["K", "Q", "J", "10", "9"])) {
    console.log("Straight");
  }

  if (check(cards,["Q", "J", "10", "9", "8"])) {
    console.log("Straight");
  }

  if (check(cards,["J", "10", "9", "8", "7"])) {
    console.log("Straight");
  }
```

My question is if there is a faster way to detect a Straight regardless of if the Straight includes J's,Q's,K's and A's.

Comment: Faster? That is not the right thing to ask; I cannot believe that you'd run into performance problems with the given code after all. Making the code more concise seems more logical. I have an issue with the code given as you indicate two ways of indicating cards: just by value `"A"` or by value and color / type `"Ah"`.

Comment: For comparison I used only the type of the cards. However they are still stored by value and color / type.

Comment: [`.includes()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes#syntax) only accepts one needle argument. The second argument is an optional start index. It's a good idea to write tests for your code.

Answer (score 1):

Your code seems fine but if you need better performance, you can use a switch statement. Also your usage of includes is incorrect, because the `includes()` method in JavaScript checks whether an array includes a certain element, but it doesn't work the way you're using it here. It doesn't accept multiple arguments for checking multiple values at once.

This is how you can use a switch statement to refractor you code:

```
switch (true) {
  case cards.includes("A") && cards.includes("2") && cards.includes("3") && cards.includes("4") && cards.includes("5"):
    console.log("Straight");
    break;
  case cards.includes("A") && cards.includes("K") && cards.includes("Q") && cards.includes("J") && cards.includes("10"):
    console.log("Royal Straight");
    break;
  case cards.includes("K") && cards.includes("Q") && cards.includes("J") && cards.includes("10") && cards.includes("9"):
    console.log("Straight");
    break;
  case cards.includes("Q") && cards.includes("J") && cards.includes("10") && cards.includes("9") && cards.includes("8"):
    console.log("Straight");
    break;
  case cards.includes("J") && cards.includes("10") && cards.includes("9") && cards.includes("8") && cards.includes("7"):
    console.log("Straight");
    break;
  default:
    console.log("No straight found.");
    break;
}
```

Comment: An `else if` would be cleaner than `switch`. Cleaner yet, keep the values in a data structure and using a loop.